# Is HYPER-V including of memory combination feature?

Tags: hyper-v, memory

I am have recent expriement with Microsoft HYPER-V SERVER 2012.

I have much VM run on small hard ware. and small memory.

Question :

is MEMORY COMBINING feature of WINDOWS 8 put into HYPER-V SERVER 2012.

I am ask specifically of free STAND BY SELF HYPER-V SERVER NOT WINDOWS SERVER.

Feature has documented HERE : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/10/07/reducing-runtime-memory-in-windows-8.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Hyper-V uses dynamic memory to address physical RAM limits. You assign the VM a minimum and a maximum amount of memory, and the VM will only use what it needs at that time.

Hyper-V does not share guest VM's memory pages with other guest VMs. I don't know if VMware does that or not, but that screams security breach to me.

Each guest OS/partition inside of Hyper-V however, still has its own memory manager and will still use memory management techniques (e.g. memory combining for Windows 8) that are unique to that operating system.

Edit: Also, it's probably not important to make the distinction between Hyper-V Server 2012 and regular Server 2012, since as far as I know there are no relevant differences between how Hyper-V works on those editions of Windows. Just licensing differences.

This feature of Windows 8 would also jive really well with the improvement in Hyper-V 2012 too, since Hyper-V can now reclaim memory from VMs over time. And it sounds like with memory combining, Windows 8 VMs would have more memory to give up after startup.